# Cannot Save Edits to File Geodatabase Replica in QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, replication

When trying to edit a File Geodatabase Replica in QGIS 2.2, everything works as expected until the user saves their edits. When pressing save, all edits revert back to their original state with no errors.  If I copy the Feature Class into a new FGDB (thus breaking it out of the replica), I can edit it without any problems.

Anyone have any thoughts on a solution for this?

FGDB Replica created in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 from a SQL SDE Geodatabase.

Comment: I think QGIS is not able to work with the FGDB connected to the replica, I had issues with FGDB that had topologies